# Is it faster to redraw multiple individual views or just redraw an entire activity?

Tags: android, performance, android-activity

I have an activity which holds a number of graphs, text and other things which I will be updating at 20 Hz. Basically every item in the activity will be updated. Is it faster to update them one by one (cycling through the views and calling invalidate), or just invalidating the entire activity?

My gut is telling me that it would be faster to redraw the entire activity, because I'm assuming there is overhead to individual calls to invalidate, but I'm really not sure.

Thanks.